# Truncate number of li's in a list if more than a certain number

Tags: jquery, truncate

I would like to achieve the following:

If there are more than 12 li's within a given ul, replace the last one with "..." and hide any that appear after the 12th one.

Can anyone throw some pointers my way?

Comment: what you tried? you need to show your effort and code for us to help you properly

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uteqat/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
<ul data-truncate="12">
```

jQuery:

```
$('[data-truncate]').each(function(){
  var n = $(this).data('truncate') -1;
  $('li', this).eq( n ).nextAll().hide().last().after('<li>...</li>');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use jQuery [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$('ul').html($('ul li').slice(0,12)).append("..");
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9gG9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#myList > li:eq(11)').nextAll().hide().end().after('<li>...</li>');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M426n/)

Note that the supplied index in `eq()` method is zero-based, and refers to the position of the element within the jQuery object, not within the DOM tree. Hence, `eq(11)` means the item 12 here.

Answer (score 0):

here is the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/w3yep/7/

sample html:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>1 </li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5 last one to see</li>
    <li>6 will be truncated</li>
    <li>7 will be truncated</li>
    <li>8 will be truncated </li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var maxToShow = 5;

    $("#mylist li").each( function(i, e){
        // truncate all li elements after the 5th
        if ( i >= maxToShow){
            // $(e).remove(); // remove it
            $(e).hide(); // or hide it
        }
    });

});
```